# Ajax posts form correctly but does not return success data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this piece of code to submit form data using ajax. Lets look at here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input.friend-request').click(function() {
        addFriend();
    });
});

function addFriend() {
    var val = 'test';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "server.php",
            data : $("#addFriend").serialize(),
            //console.log(data);
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data==1) {
                    //$('input.friend-request').hide();
                    $("#addFriendSuccess").html('friend request sent').fadeIn(1000);
                    $("#addFriendSuccess").fadeOut(5000);
                } else {
                    alert('something is wrong');
                }
            }
        },"json");
 }
```

And this is the server.php file codes that handles form data insertion into database.

```
include 'db.php';

$session = $_POST['session'];
$friend = $_POST['friend'];
if ($session = $_POST['session'] && $friend = $_POST['friend']) {
    $newSql = "INSERT INTO friend_request(user_id,friend_id) VALUES ('$session', '$friend')";
    $addQuery = mysqli_query($db, $newSql);
    echo '1';
}
```

At this stage everything works fine and data inserts correctly into database. If data is successful `echo '1'` is returned here:

```
if (data==1) {
    $("#addFriendSuccess").html('friend request sent').fadeIn(1000);
    $("#addFriendSuccess").fadeOut(5000);
}
```

I want to show the user a message in proper div(addFriendSuccess) and that div is included in the body. But it does not work and does not show any message to the user. Even `console.log(data)` does not log anything. What is the possible wrong happening here?

Comment: did you check in jquery debugger if it pauses in this line: `$("#addFriendSuccess").html('friend request sent').fadeIn(1000);`

Comment: @ekraner how i can do that? thanks

Comment: In chrome you can press F12 and choose Sources and then select your page. Then put a break to that line. Also this might be also related with how Ajax works. Ajax is asynchronous. The call to $.ajax() just initiates the ajax call. Then the line of of code after it is executed. You can usue deferreds: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/ajax-deferreds

Comment: in your OP (Original Post), you say _"At this stage everything works fine and data inserts correctly into database."_ What do you mean? When is it successful? and when is it not successful?

Comment: I meant when the button is clicked the form is submitted and passes data to server.php and that page inserts data successfully into my database tables. But on success i wanted to show the message to the user that in addFriendSuccess div which is not working.

Comment: weird, its working well on my local.. do you see `1` returning in your console?

Comment: Nope i don't see any data if i console.log. i tried it simply :  `if (data==1) 
         {
            
             console.log('friend request sent');
         }` but nothing is logs into my console. Really can't figure out where is the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this:

```
function AddFriend() {
     return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "server.php",
        data : $("#addFriend").serialize(),
     });
}

function AddFriendError(x, y, z) {
    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
}

function AddFriendResult(jqXHR, textStatus)
{
    var data = JSON.parse(jqXHR);//I changed this, you can also try this again below..

    if (data === "1") { //or data === "1"
        $("#addFriendSuccess").html('friend request sent').fadeIn(1000);
        $("#addFriendSuccess").fadeOut(5000);
    }
}

$.when(AddFriend()).then(AddFriendResult, AddFriendError);
```

Comment: @ekraner It shows deferreds is not defined. How to fix that? Thanks

Comment: `$.when.apply...` should be within `AddFriend()` function, previous code had a syntax error, can you try again?

Comment: @ekraner it does not seem to be working. splashes into console 'object is not a function'. Can you try my original post in your local. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: I posted another version, which is simpler. Can you try that one? Please use Chrome jQuery debugger to see what you got here as data: `if (data === 1) {..`

Comment: Thanks. Now your code adds records into db as well as mine. But still success function return is not working. I have paused it as you said. Please see the screenshot [link](http://postimg.org/image/3yum97uj7/)

Comment: please pause the application in this line `if (data === 1) {`, and mouse over `data`, which will display the content of it, then take a screenshot. you need to add a break point.

Comment: data is undefined! how? please have a look: [link](http://postimg.org/image/ymud7bz8b/)  . I really appreciate your time and help. Thanks

Comment: can you also share how `jqXHR` looks like?

Comment: in the image you shared, did you see that the value of textStatus  is "success"? I think you can use this for your success condition. Please see the update in my code. This status shows that your ajax run successfully.

Comment: this does not seem to be working either. I tried `if(textStatus = "success")`. what i am messing with who knows. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer. But i don't know if it would be appropriate. I am still in problem.

Comment: your code has double or triple equal signs right? `if(textStatus == "success")`

Comment: also in previous screen shots, you did not put the break in this line : `if(textStatus = "success")` that is why you got data undefined, because the line that assigns a value to it was not run.

Comment: i tried this with double and triple equal signs. But still in dark why its not working.

Comment: you need to put a break to `if(textStatus = "success")` line and mouse over the textStatus and send me the screen shot. You should also try `var data = JSON.parse(jqXHR);` if you have not, and send the print screen for data.

Comment: hello it simply worked this way :  `if (data === "1")`. previously i used 'if(data ===1)'. Still thinking why it worked for wrapping with quotes.

Comment: @facebook-1422110434758753 can you please mark my post as the answer?